# Button remain pressed with "then break end" between PressMouseButton(1) and ReleaseMouseButton(1)

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

When executing a macro, while holding LMB + RMB, sometimes the button remains pressed. How to fix this without resorting to PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)? Is it even possible?

```
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
     if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
      repeat
       PressMouseButton(1)
       Sleep(33) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
       ReleaseMouseButton(1)
       PressMouseButton(1)
       Sleep(33) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
       ReleaseMouseButton(1)
       PressMouseButton(1)
       Sleep(33) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
       ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
     end
    end
```

p.s.  it doesn't need to be looped, it should be executed to the end and stop, or stop earlier when the button is released.

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
      for i = 1, 3 do  -- press LMB 3 times and stop
         PressMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(33)
         ReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(33)
         if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! But now it is executed to the end and does not stop when the button is released.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't need to be looped, it should be executed to the end and stop, or stop earlier when the button is released.